# Rainbow legend in R

Tags: r, plot

[image]I have a the death rate for ages 0-100 plotted in one graph. It's very color full but for a reader there is no explanation who is age 0, age 40 or age 100 for example. I have seen rainbow legends is pictures online, but gained no answer on how to write one out myself. The line I use to plot is

```
plot(m, series = "total", datatype="rate", plot.type="time", xlab="Years", main="Total death rate")
```

What can I change to get the rainbow legend? And is there a call for writing out the grid lines in the graph area?

Snippet of the data is

```
structure(c(0.107446, 0.02901, 0.015211, 0.010825, 0.008799, 
0.006939, 0.110958, 0.028299, 0.014543, 0.010939, 0.00893, 0.007335, 
0.091162, 0.026333, 0.013556, 0.009593, 0.007193, 0.005984, 0.097073, 
0.026088, 0.012508, 0.008976, 0.007057, 0.005734, 0.089595, 0.022413, 
0.011188, 0.008234, 0.006767, 0.005522, 0.093491, 0.02269, 0.011209, 
0.009104, 0.00724, 0.006003, 0.08592, 0.019631, 0.009459, 0.006521, 
0.005931, 0.004634, 0.080883, 0.019495, 0.009131, 0.006662, 0.004753, 
0.004184, 0.09061, 0.021713, 0.008999, 0.006332, 0.004717, 0.004221, 
0.076158, 0.016583, 0.008261, 0.005645, 0.004305, 0.003866, 0.078229, 
0.019572, 0.008195, 0.005844, 0.004747, 0.003715, 0.07538, 0.01746, 
0.008253, 0.006093, 0.004857, 0.003771, 0.074146, 0.01849, 0.008344, 
0.005719, 0.004848, 0.004174, 0.072209, 0.015411, 0.007567, 0.005166, 
0.004282, 0.003863, 0.076099, 0.016082, 0.006845, 0.005483, 0.004198, 
0.003673, 0.077503, 0.017572, 0.007786, 0.005492, 0.004817, 0.003448, 
0.072559, 0.018363, 0.007551, 0.005644, 0.004607, 0.003867, 0.067097, 
0.014814, 0.007276, 0.005583, 0.004591, 0.003869, 0.066543, 0.019021, 
0.011272, 0.009122, 0.007382, 0.00635, 0.071861, 0.016772, 0.009663, 
0.007277, 0.006925, 0.005022, 0.072476, 0.014029, 0.007611, 0.005485, 
0.004887, 0.003871, 0.064407, 0.012097, 0.005361, 0.004211, 0.003923, 
0.002647, 0.062224, 0.011398, 0.005304, 0.003305, 0.003032, 0.002257, 
0.057591, 0.010665, 0.004426, 0.002968, 0.002496, 0.002317, 0.061385, 
0.012738, 0.005614, 0.003438, 0.003094, 0.002173, 0.057092, 0.009833, 
0.004379, 0.003359, 0.002478, 0.002311, 0.056902, 0.009439, 0.004451, 
0.002798, 0.002614, 0.002104, 0.060825, 0.011348, 0.0047, 0.003323, 
0.002893, 0.002541, 0.061088, 0.011606, 0.004853, 0.002955, 0.002427, 
0.002494, 0.059242, 0.008986, 0.003939, 0.002715, 0.002199, 0.002218, 
0.057243, 0.007084, 0.003793, 0.002429, 0.00217, 0.001911, 0.057835, 
0.008646, 0.003879, 0.002627, 0.002119, 0.001695, 0.05217, 0.007877, 
0.003303, 0.002461, 0.001783, 0.001602, 0.049842, 0.007063, 0.003305, 
0.002104, 0.001544, 0.001379, 0.048754, 0.006322, 0.003006, 0.00226, 
0.001961, 0.001548, 0.047834, 0.006098, 0.002681, 0.002307, 0.001882, 
0.001623, 0.045679, 0.006773, 0.00329, 0.002311, 0.001794, 0.00182, 
0.046924, 0.006226, 0.003433, 0.002487, 0.001901, 0.001666, 0.044641, 
0.005054, 0.003138, 0.001933, 0.001878, 0.001403, 0.041354, 0.004579, 
0.0025, 0.001735, 0.001648, 0.001228, 0.040073, 0.004021, 0.002109, 
0.001469, 0.001155, 0.001245, 0.038778, 0.004742, 0.002258, 0.001759, 
0.001354, 0.001152, 0.031958, 0.002932, 0.001877, 0.001526, 0.001338, 
0.001155, 0.030943, 0.003213, 0.00218, 0.001858, 0.001429, 0.001144, 
0.032905, 0.003633, 0.002685, 0.001904, 0.001783, 0.001572, 0.030931, 
0.003345, 0.002049, 0.00173, 0.00147, 0.001261, 0.026955, 0.002292, 
0.001541, 0.001232, 0.001046, 0.001022, 0.025469, 0.002239, 0.001559, 
0.001314, 0.000903, 0.000907, 0.023388, 0.001881, 0.001435, 0.001149, 
0.000908, 0.000592, 0.023167, 0.002012, 0.001074, 0.001072, 0.00101, 
0.000708, 0.020801, 0.00185, 0.00138, 0.001153, 0.000802, 0.000886, 
0.021411, 0.001977, 0.001321, 0.000922, 0.000752, 0.000671, 0.020338, 
0.001702, 0.001157, 0.000908, 0.000866, 0.000721, 0.019017, 0.001688, 
0.001052, 0.000873, 0.000653, 0.000666, 0.018535, 0.001483, 0.001013, 
0.000808, 0.000684, 0.00048, 0.017848, 0.001449, 0.001057, 0.000808, 
0.000726, 0.00064, 0.017602, 0.001388, 0.001117, 0.000751, 0.000649, 
0.000526, 0.017921, 0.001424, 0.000889, 0.000784, 0.000703, 5e-04, 
0.01597, 0.001387, 0.00081, 0.00084, 0.000623, 0.000619, 0.016763, 
0.001251, 0.000897, 0.000707, 0.000544, 0.000613, 0.016616, 0.001419, 
0.000669, 0.000624, 0.000754, 0.000573, 0.01613, 0.001077, 0.000762, 
0.000688, 0.00068, 0.000546, 0.01582, 0.00105, 0.00088, 0.000703, 
0.000439, 0.000556, 0.015948, 0.000929, 0.000735, 0.000528, 0.000491, 
0.000534, 0.014965, 8e-04, 0.000593, 0.000656, 0.000517, 0.000519, 
0.013486, 0.000925, 0.00065, 6e-04, 0.00039, 0.000564, 0.012713, 
0.00092, 0.000597, 0.000437, 0.000664, 0.000505, 0.012879, 0.000723, 
0.000483, 0.000443, 0.000464, 0.00035, 0.012784, 0.000719, 0.000518, 
0.000508, 0.000426, 0.000391, 0.011642, 0.000668, 0.000535, 0.000449, 
0.000579, 0.00039, 0.011299, 0.000668, 0.000467, 0.000547, 0.000446, 
0.000511, 0.011514, 0.000598, 0.000458, 0.000355, 0.000285, 0.000356, 
0.010822, 0.000602, 0.00046, 0.000486, 0.000364, 4e-04, 0.009783, 
0.000588, 0.000414, 0.000388, 0.000298, 0.000391, 0.009622, 0.000725, 
0.000436, 0.000234, 0.00036, 0.000507, 0.008408, 0.000701, 0.000397, 
0.000311, 0.000351, 0.000378, 0.008115, 0.000522, 0.000407, 0.00027, 
0.000301, 0.000332, 0.007953, 0.000501, 0.000333, 0.000379, 0.000349, 
0.000238, 0.007689, 0.000531, 0.000274, 0.000314, 0.000315, 0.000393, 
0.007626, 0.000673, 0.000387, 0.000264, 0.000369, 0.000324, 0.006958, 
0.000567, 0.000283, 0.000295, 0.000303, 0.000221, 0.006842, 0.000412, 
0.000221, 0.000231, 0.000183, 0.000195, 0.006798, 0.000427, 0.000278, 
0.000294, 0.000315, 0.000183, 0.007002, 0.000352, 0.000271, 0.000237, 
2e-04, 0.000189, 0.006483, 0.000421, 0.00016, 0.000229, 0.000113, 
0.000137, 0.006938, 0.000472, 0.00029, 0.000244, 0.000166, 0.000216, 
0.00605, 0.000569, 0.000256, 0.000236, 0.000233, 0.000166, 0.006215, 
0.000426, 0.000329, 0.000266, 0.000192, 0.000169, 0.006023, 0.00051, 
0.000276, 0.000205, 0.000137, 0.000191, 0.00588, 0.000422, 0.000287, 
0.000157, 0.000285, 0.000168, 0.006158, 0.000392, 0.000282, 0.000266, 
0.000156, 0.000141, 0.006149, 0.000389, 0.000225, 0.000181, 0.000217, 
6.8e-05, 0.005339, 0.000281, 0.000256, 0.000259, 0.000144, 0.000169, 
0.004757, 3e-04, 0.000241, 0.000247, 0.00018, 0.000117, 0.004349, 
0.000324, 0.000161, 0.000127, 0.00022, 0.000136, 0.003988, 0.000261, 
0.000191, 8.8e-05, 0.000166, 0.000138, 0.003805, 0.000352, 0.000131, 
0.000141, 0.000168, 0.00015, 0.003541, 0.000443, 0.000139, 0.000174, 
0.000125, 0.000112, 0.003521, 0.000312, 0.000191, 0.000139, 0.000113, 
0.000125, 0.003343, 0.000233, 0.000172, 8e-05, 8.3e-05, 7.8e-05, 
0.00345, 0.000223, 0.00011, 6.4e-05, 1e-04, 6.5e-05, 0.003661, 
0.000276, 0.000211, 0.000154, 0.000106, 1e-04, 0.003334, 0.00026, 
0.000275, 0.00011, 0.000109, 9.5e-05, 0.003154, 0.000316, 0.000205, 
0.000153, 0.00011, 0.000109, 0.003134, 0.000213, 0.000126, 7.5e-05, 
8.7e-05, 8.7e-05, 0.002427, 0.000415, 0.000141, 0.000198, 8.6e-05, 
0.00013, 0.002857, 0.000293, 0.000137, 0.00015, 0.000114, 0.000107, 
0.002503, 0.000314, 0.000145, 8.8e-05, 0.000109, 0.000113, 0.002501, 
0.000222, 0.00016, 6.7e-05, 9.7e-05, 8.9e-05, 0.002506, 0.000327, 
0.000219, 0.000196, 4.8e-05, 7.7e-05, 0.002578, 0.00025, 0.000126, 
0.000109, 0.000111, 3.8e-05, 0.002061, 0.00026, 4.4e-05, 0.000117, 
0.000108, 5.5e-05, 0.002597, 0.000156, 0.000129, 0.000105, 0.000125, 
6.3e-05, 0.002689, 0.000123, 9.5e-05, 0.000136, 9.6e-05, 7.1e-05, 
0.002183, 0.000217, 4.3e-05, 0.000119, 5.9e-05, 9.5e-05), .Dim = c(6L, 
115L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), c("1900", 
"1901", "1902", "1903", "1904", "1905", "1906", "1907", "1908", 
"1909", "1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", "1914", "1915", "1916", 
"1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", "1923", "1924", 
"1925", "1926", "1927", "1928", "1929", "1930", "1931", "1932", 
"1933", "1934", "1935", "1936", "1937", "1938", "1939", "1940", 
"1941", "1942", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1946", "1947", "1948", 
"1949", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1956", 
"1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", 
"1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", 
"1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", 
"1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", 
"1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014")))
```

Comment: Please include a sample data. If your data is not to big, you can use dput(m).

Comment: if you use `?legend` it will give you the answer. But you can use `colorRampPalette` and give it the colors and the breaks. In legend use `col = palette` and you'll have your colors. If you had sample data I would do it but there isn't any

Comment: I'm happy to provide my data, but don't know how to do this. The console cut the data.

Comment: Provide just some small sample of your data, by using something like `dput(head(yourData, 10))`

Comment: The function `grid` will let you add a background grid.

Comment: grid work perfect

Comment: Note, **the rainbow palette shouldn’t be used**. [It’s extremely misleading](https://paperpile.com/shared/wsSfAQ). Use a different scale, e.g. from [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) (there’s an [R package for it](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how you went from the data to the plot. 
I suspect that the color was actually based on `age` 
which was not provided, but since that was not the point, 
I just made up some value. Also, because you used the 
`rainbow` color palette I did too, but as noted by @KonradRudolph
there are problems with `rainbow` and you might want to 
consider a different palette.

To address your questions, the `SDMTools` package
includes a `legend.gradient` function. The function `grid`
will add the background grid that you want. I use all of 
that in the example below. It will have to be adjusted to 
match the way you actually plotted this, but this should 
be close enough for you to figure it out. I called the 
data structure that you provided for data `DR`.

```
library(SDMTools)
age = floor((log(DR[,1])+6)*17)
plot(colnames(DR), log(DR[1,]), type="l", ylim=c(-10,0),
    col=rainbow(102)[age[1]], xlab="Years", ylab="log Death Rate")
for(i in 2:6) { 
    lines(colnames(DR), log(DR[i,]), col=rainbow(102)[age[i]]) }

LegLoc   = cbind(x =c(1900,1903,1903,1900), y =c(-8,-8,-10,-10))
legend.gradient(pnts=LegLoc, cols=rainbow(102), 
    limits=c(1, 100), title = "age")
grid()
```

[image: gradient.legend Example]

Comment: Thanks. The initial plot was made from a demogdata and the colors came with that.